# brian2 not importing in anaconda python distribution

Tags: python, locale

When I try to `import brian2` in the python distribution of Anaconda I get this error message:

```
>> import brian2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named brian

>>> import brian2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/brian2/__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pylab import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pylab.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.pylab import *
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1131, in <module>
    rcParams = rc_params()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 975, in rc_params
    return rc_params_from_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1100, in rc_params_from_file
    config_from_file = _rc_params_in_file(fname, fail_on_error)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1018, in _rc_params_in_file
    with _open_file_or_url(fname) as fd:
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py", line 1000, in _open_file_or_url
    encoding = locale.getdefaultlocale()[1]
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 543, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "//anaconda/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 475, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: UTF-8
```

I do not understand why? Is it something to do with `matplotlib` and `pylab`?

Comment: The LANG or LANGUAGE environment variable is set to `UTF-8` which is invalid. Try `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` in your shell and run Python again. If you tell me what country you live in and what your native language is, there may be a more appropriate definition for LANG.

Comment: have you followed these instructions while installing brian2? http://brian2.readthedocs.org/en/2.0b4/introduction/install.html

Comment: The anaconda version didn't work thus I used the normal `pip` installation of `brian2`.
Now it imports peacefully using Apple supplied python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug with OSX in that they are not setting their local env variables to standard values:

As @msw says in the comments the fix is to

```
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

in your bashrc.

Also see:

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5420
https://github.com/bempp/bempp/issues/260
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/5919
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11608
https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11694

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/5931 is one proposed fix.  This should be 'fixed' in the next mpl release.

If anyone (everyone?) who owns a mac knows how to report a bug to Apple, this would be a good thing to do.

Comment: I have reported this bug to Apple, through a mail and hyperlinked this page.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://anaconda.org/brian-team/brian2

The installation for anaconda is

```
conda install -c http://conda.anaconda.org/brian-team brian2
```